# Maven commands are not working,but maven works in eclipse

Tags: maven-3

When I type any Maven command like `mvn -version`, `mvn clean install` etc. they are not working. But the same maven installation is working properly in eclipse. In the command prompt I get the below option for all maven commands: [image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in your Eclipse, you use different maven installation (maybe embedded one). 
Firstly the problem is not with maven itself, but probably with wrong usage of java in maven or java is not set properly. If your maven would be properly installed and configured you should see something like this:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T18:29:23+01:00)
Maven home: c:\apache-maven-3.2.5
Java version: 1.7.0_111, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\appl\JDK7\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

please provide some more information about `java -version` and your environment paths. Also try to look at your `mvn.bat`.